# Command suggestions in winedt

Tags: macros, winedt

How do I get command suggestions in Winedt like in texmaker? I have tried exploring the options but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's already the case. Which version of WinEdt  do you have?

Comment: I have Winedt 9.0

Comment: I don't remeber since when there's command completion, maybe 9.1. Anyway you should update to the last version (10.0).

Comment: I got the latest version. My problem is solved. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome . As there a number of extensions on WinEdt.org, I suggest you take a look and install at least the `Contributions Manager` if you should decide to install a ‘contribution’.

Comment: @Bernard, would you mind to move your comments to an answer, so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

WinEdt has command completion, as far as I remember, since version 9.1 
You should update to the present version (`10.0`), which brings a  number of significant improvements, among which the support of bidirectional text.

The community of users' site `WinEdt.org` now has a useful `Contributions Manager` which eases (un)installing and  updating contributions from users.